# How can I enable my worksheets in Excel to auto-update the filters I have applied to them

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, office365, microsoft-excel-2016

I have looked on the other threads to no avail for this. I have a few sheets in my workbook, with one being a data sheet and the others pulling data from it. I have set a filter in these sheets to not show anything that shows up as 'false', which is great until I add data into the master data sheet. I would love anybody to help with making it possible for the other sheets to automatically update, show/unshow data, without me having to reapply the filter all the time! I hope this makes sense!

I have tried using this code (found from other threads on this site), but doesnt seem to be working for me, what am I doing wrong!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Me.FilterMode = True Then
    With Application
       .EnableEvents = False
       .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook
        .CustomViews.Add ViewName:="Mine", RowColSettings:=True
      Me.AutoFilterMode = False
        .CustomViews("Mine").Show
        .CustomViews("Mine").Delete
    End With


     With Application
       .EnableEvents = True
       .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

So it will [trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) on specific Targets when they change. You haven't checked the Target against any condition so it won't trigger. You should check if the Target changing is within your filtered range like

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10") is Nothing Then
```